# Windows Server 2012 DNS returns a useless tautology

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, internal-dns, nslookup

For one hostname - `myaccount.cargowise.com` - our Windows Server 2012 DNS seemingly returns a useless and tautological answer; it resolves `myaccount.cargowise.com` to itself without providing an IP address. No other domain names seem to be affected.

Attempting to access the website unsurprisingly reports that the domain name could not be resolved.

We have had this issue for over a week - I have tried to search for a solution, but since there is no error message it is not very "google-able". The server seems to think it is successfully answering. So far, we have worked around it by adding an entry to the `drivers/etc/hosts` file on the PCs of users who need this website.

```
$ nslookup myaccount.cargowise.com
Server:  (internal DNS)
Address:  172.30.0.78

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    myaccount.cargowise.com
```

I see no obvious issue with the domain itself:

```
$ nslookup myaccount.cargowise.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    syd-1.oc.wisegrid.net
Addresses:  180.235.156.133
          180.235.156.134
          180.235.156.135
          180.235.156.131
          180.235.156.132
          180.235.156.136
Aliases:  myaccount.cargowise.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, we have figured this one out:

We have a forward lookup zone for `wisegrid.net`, but the entry for `syd-1.oc.wisegrid.net` was typoed as `sys-1.oc.wisegrid.net`

So we resolved this by adding a forward lookup for `syd-1.oc.wisegrid.net`